# TreeMap Element does not removed

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I created a map and then sort the values and put them in a TreeMap. But the problem is when I invoke the remove() method on Treemap, the element is not removed.
Does anybody have any idea what the problem is?

Here is my code:

```
Map<String , Double> map=new HashMap<String, Double>();
TreeMap<String, Double> sortedItems = sortMap(map);
sortedItems.remove("I put the key here as a string");


  public TreeMap<String, Double> sortMap(Map<String, Double> map) {
        HashMap<String, Double> map2 = new HashMap<String, Double>(map);
        TreeMap<String, Double> sortedMap = SortByValue(map2);
        return sortedMap;
    }

public TreeMap<String, Double> SortByValue
        (HashMap<String, Double> map) {
    ValueComparator vc = new ValueComparator(map);
    TreeMap<String, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Double>(vc);
    sortedMap.putAll(map);
    return sortedMap;
}
class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Double> map;

    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.map = base;
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (map.get(a) >= map.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
```

Comment: A key is "found" when compare() returns 0. Your compare never returns 0, so no key is ever found to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return 0; when you expect a match.  The way to solve this is to compare the key which it is otherwise a match.  This way the same key will match, but only the same key.

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
    int cmp = -map.get(a).compareTo(map.get(b));
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = a.compareTo(b);
    return cmp;
}
```

This way String keys which map to the same Double are seen as different iff they are different Strings.

Comment: Now with this compare method you wrote, the treemap is not sorted properly

Comment: @HimanUCC What do you mean by "not sorted properly"? if it is supposed to be reverse sorted, I have changed the code.

Answer (score 1):

> *returning 0 would merge keys*

Returning 0 means the elements are equal. If you don't return 0, elements are never equal. Your `TreeMap` uses the given `Comparator` to `put` and `remove`. Your `Comparator` never identifies two keys as equal and therefore cannot remove anything.

Comment: In fact the map is sorted properly and I can see the elements inside the treemap that are sorted. the problem is with remove() method that I mentioned .

Comment: @HimanUCC Yes, both `remove` and `put` use your given `Comparator`. Try adding an entry with the same key to your `TreeMap`. Instead of overwriting the previous entry, you'll get a new entry. Your `Comparator` is wrong.